# Min Heap Delete Min out of order?

Tags: c++, heap, dijkstra

Sorry, beginner coder here.
I found a min heap implementation online and put it into my Weighted graph.

```
class Heap : public weightedGraph
{
public: Heap();
    ~Heap();
    void insert(double element);
    double deletemin()
    {
        double min = heap.front();
        heap[0] = heap.at(heap.size()-1);
        heap.pop_back();
        heapifydown(0);
        return min;
    };

    void print();   

    int size()
    {return heap.size();}


private:
 int left(int parent);
 int right(int parent);
 int parent(int child);
 void heapifyup(int index);
 void heapifydown(int index);

private:
 vector<double> heap;
};

Heap::Heap() {}

Heap::~Heap()
void Heap::insert(double element)
{
   heap.push_back(element);
   heapifyup(heap.size()-1);
}

void Heap::heapifyup(int index)
{
 while((index>0) && (parent(index) >=0) && (heap[parent(index)] > heap[index]))
 {
     double tmp = heap[parent(index)];
     heap[parent(index)] = heap[index];
     heap[index] = tmp;
     index = parent(index);
 }
}

void Heap::heapifydown(int index)
{
 int child = left(index);

 if((child > 0) && (right(index) > 0) && (heap[child]>heap[right(index)]))
 {
     child = right(index);
 }
 if(child > 0)
 {
    double tmp = heap[index];
    heap[index] = heap[child];
    heap[child] = tmp;
    heapifydown(child);
 }
}

int Heap::left(int parent)
{
 int i = ( parent <<1) + 1; 
 return(i<heap.size()) ? i : - 1;
}

int Heap::right(int parent)
{
 int i = ( parent <<1) + 2; 
 return(i<heap.size()) ? i : - 1;
}

int Heap::parent(int child)
{
 if(child != 0)
 {
     int i = (child - 1) >>1;
     return i;
 }
 return -1;
}
```

After I add all the vertices, when I run deletemin until the heap is empty, but some vertices are not in order.

41
153
288
292
491
778
1842
1869
2995
3035
3902
4664
4827
5436
5447
5705
6334
6868
7711
8723
8942
9040
9741
9894
9961
11478
11538
11942
12316
12382
12859
14604
14771
15141
15724
17035
17421
17673
18467
**19264**
18716
19169
19718
19912
21726
22190
22648
23281
23811
24464
25667
**20037**
26299
26500
**25547**
***16827***
26962
27644
**19895**
28145
**27529**
28253
28703
29358
30106
30333
31322
32391
32662
32757

There might be some others. Any reason why this would be?

Comment: I'd start by writing a bit of code to verify the heap property, that you can run before and after each insertion, removal, etc., so you can at least pinpoint what's happening when.

Comment: Why do you inherit from `weightedGraph`? That doesn’t make sense, a heap is *not* a weighted graph.

Comment: my apologies, I didn't realize I left it there when I was toying around with the vertex class. @Jerry, Let me try that.

Comment: output: Heap = 41 491 6334 2995 5436 15724 9961 5705 4827 18467 19169 28145 23281 16827 11478 29358 26500 26962 11942 24464
Extract Min-
41 491 2995 4827 5436 5705 6334 9961 11942 15724 16827 18467 19169 23281 11478 24464 26500 28145 26962 29358

Comment: why not use the std heap/prio queue (not sure about the name)?

Comment: The obvious reason is the code you copied from a random Internet source is wrong. Don't do that. You must learn to evaluate trustworthiness of all code you use.  If it's not trustworthy, you must invest the work to verify and test it before use, not count on calls for help on SO. Even if you get some hints, how trustworthy are they?

Answer (score 0):

Check your heapifydown logic. You are not comparing the parents weight with children weight
You are just exchanging blindly. You are only comparing children's weights.